# external hard disk unmounting problem

Tags: external-hdd

I'm using Kubuntu after changing from ubuntu. I could unmount the external HD safely in ubuntu but in Kubuntu I tried using the safely remove drive option on the notification bar and also through file manager but no success. The external HD is not turning off even after the safely remove drive option, which i used in the ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Please help

Comment: Please notice the difference between unmounting a partition and ejecting a drive. If you unmount a partition, the buffers will be flushed (what should be written to it will be written) and it will *not* be available for normal read and write operations. If you unmount all partitions in a drive, it will be safe to unplug or to turn off the power, but unmounting does not turn off the power; it is possible to mount the partition(s) again. If you eject a drive, you unmount the partition(s) on the drive and turn off the power. It must be unplugged and plugged back to connect (mount) again.

Comment: I know this already but I needed a simple thing to eject my external hard disk which I already found after posting this question.

Comment: I am glad that you solved your problem :-) Please share your solution with us for example by posting an own answer (or by editing your question or in a simple comment).

Comment: I have installed the disks utility app from the software centre. It has turn off option which helped me turning off the external hard disk.

Comment: Please write your answer in the "your answer" below and remove it from the question.

Answer (score 1):

Found answer for my own question. Here's the answer. Install 'Disks' Utility app from software centre. It has the option to turn off the external hard disk.[image]